# Memory Management for Lookup Tables with string keys in C++

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I am implementing a dual-key (int and string) lookup table in C++ and would like to know how I should write a destructor for it.

The lookup table API allows users to insert and lookup a named object into the table. Under-the-covers, a unique int key is automatically assigned to the string which holds the name of the object. After insertion the inserted object can be looked up by its string name or int value.

Here is the gist of the implementation.

```
template <class VALUE>
class COLLECTION
{
    public;
    typedef int IDX;
    typedef std::map< std::string , IDX >   NAME_TO_IDX;
    typedef std::map< IDX, std::string >   IDX_TO_NAME;
    typedef std::map<IDX, VALUE*>          IDX_TO_VAL;
...
    void insert( const std::string name, VALUE* v )
    {   
        m_name_to_idx_map[name]       = m_next_idx;
        m_idx_to_name_map[m_next_idx] = name;
        m_idx_to_val_map[m_next_idx] = v;
        ++m_next_idx;
    }
    VALUE* get_value( const IDX idx ) { return m_idx_to_val_map[idx]; }
    VALUE* get_value( const std::string name )
    ....
    private:
    int           m_next_idx;
    NAME_TO_IDX   m_name_to_idx_map;
    IDX_TO_NAME   m_idx_to_name_map;
    IDX_TO_VAL    m_idx_to_val_map;
```

How would I write a destructor for this class?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to write a destructor?

Comment: @KerrekSB Not trying to be facetious here, but I want to reclaim memory? Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: You're missing the part where you're *claiming* any memory! I don't see anything that requires destruction. Do you?

Comment: VALUE* could point to something on the heap.

Comment: It could, or it could not. We will never know, since your interface doesn't contain *any* kind of contract, preconditions or requirements. It's true mystery programming :-)

Comment: @unshul Your design has a flaw.  You don't know 1) Whether `VALUE` was allocated or not and 2) even if was allocated, what allocation function was used so as to call the correct deallocation function (was it allocated with `new`, `new[]`, `malloc`, `HeapAlloc`, etc. etc.)

Comment: @KerrekSB. Ok, can you give me a concrete example of how I might update the API to encode the fact that VALUE* always points to something on the heap?

Comment: @unshul -- See my comment.  You can't, unless the user tells you how to deallocate the memory.

Comment: Absolutely: `void insert(const std::string& key, std::unique_ptr<VALUE> value)`, bingo. If you hate expressing requirements in code, you could also pass a raw pointer and add a comment above the function declaration that says `// Takes owernship of *value and calls "delete" on the pointer.`. (It's important to be clear that users must not, say, pass in pointers obtained from `malloc` or from array-`new`, so just "takes ownership" isn't precise enough. But the unique pointer leaves no ambiguities.)

Comment: Better (on average) to use a `vector`s instead of `map`s for `m_idx_to_name_map` and `m_idx_to_val_map`, as the indices are contiguous (assuming you don't support deletions).

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie. I want to create this new type of collection--it is similar in spirit to std::map, except that it maintains an extra dictionary of references to names. I will look at the implementation of std::map for pointers.

Comment: It's also questionable why you would have this seemingly pointless indirection and the conflated responsibilities of your class. Why not just have a `map<int, VALUE>`? If the user cares for indirection, she can use `VALUE = std::unqiue_ptr<X>`.

Comment: You might also consider [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) for such bi-directional mappings.

Comment: Kerrek's suggestion to separate responsibilities is by far the best option here, and `unique_ptr` a sound second, but FWIW another is to have a template policy parameter or constructor argument specify a functor that can be invoked to deallocate (if necessary) the `VALUE*`.  Separately, it's best practice to reserve all-uppercase identifiers for preprocessor macros, excepting single-letter identifiers which can be used for template parameters.

Comment: Instead of writing my own class I am going to use Boost.MultiIndex http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html What is the StackOverflow etiquette for this thread? Meaning how should I close this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid writing manual deallocating memory owned by all `VALUE*` in destructor - probably you should use smart pointers.

C++11 provides `std::shared_ptr` which you can use for storing `VALUE*`,

```
typedef std::map<IDX, std::shared_ptr<VALUE> > IDX_TO_VAL;
```

If you can use boost library then you can use `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

The only heap allocated portion is possibly the VALUE* (Not a huge fan of the uppercases).
For your destructor, you have have to loop through the map and delete all of the relevant pointers as follows

```
for(auto iter = IDX_TO_VAL.begin(); iter != IDX_TO_VAL.end(); ++iter)
{
    delete (*iter).second;
}
```

Comment: @unshul *What if VALUE points to something allocated on the heap?* -- And what if it doesn't?  You have undefined behavior if you attempt to call `delete` on that value.  That's the flaw in your design -- you can't assume where that address comes from that you're populating your map with.